# Save several data frames with different names with loop

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have three different data frames and I want all of them be saved with different names.

I got the data frames within a list as well as the names.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to run two loops simultaneously in R and if I embed one loop into the other it is just overwriting.

```
 for (f in dataframe_list){
                for (i in names){
                        write.csv(f, paste0(i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
                }

        }
```

That is an example for my embedded version.

Does anyone has a clue how to solve it ?

Comment: Pls `dput(dataframe_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One loop (over data frame indices) should be enough.

```r
for (i in seq_along(dataframe_list)) {
  write.csv(dataframe_list[[i]], paste0(i, '.csv'), row.names=F)
}
```

To name the csv files according to the names of the data frames:

```r
for (df.name in names(dataframe_list)) {
  write.csv(dataframe_list[[df.name]], paste0(df.name, '.csv'), row.names=F)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !This works, but it names the csv outputs 1,2,3. It would be perfect if I could name them according to the names of the data frames.

Comment: No problem, see my updated answer.