# write multiple table with different filename in R

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple tables want to save them as csv with original names.
Here is my example :  `df.a01,df.a02,df.a03,etc.`

I tried

```
list <- list(df.a01,df.a02,df.a03)

for (i in 1:length(list)) {
  write.csv(list[i], paste0(i, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

but it's not work.

I got `1.csv,2.csv,3.csv`,but I want to is like `a01.csv,a02.csv,a03.csv`.

I also tried [Save several data frames with different names with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800045/save-several-data-frames-with-different-names-with-loop), still can't get what I desired.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace `paste0(i, '.csv')` with `sprintf("a%02d.csv", i)`

Comment: @Darren Tsai, thank you for comment, if change like ```list <- list(Mary, Rogen, Kevein)````,how can I do?

Comment: `df.name <- c("Mary", "Rogen", "Kevein"); for(i in df.name) { write.csv(get(i), paste0(i, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE) }`

Comment: ```i``` will according to tables all I assign right? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it is not regarded as good practice to convert variable names into string, even if it is possible (e.g. this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577412/how-to-convert-variable-object-name-into-string)).

But this is not your main problem : when you define your list, you do not set name to its elements, so the variable name are "lost" (take a look at your list to see it : `names(list)`).

Lastly, you shouldn't use a function name to define a variable. `list` is a function in R (which is used to build... list) : as you're replacing it with you're new variable, you cannot use anymore the function.

A good workflow for setting name variables and using them in a loop would look like something like this :

```
l = list()

l["df1"] = data.frame(t = c(1,2,3))
l["df2"] = data.frame(t = c(1,2,3))
l["df3"] = data.frame(t = c(1,2,3))

for (i in 1:length(l)){
  write.csv(l[[i]], paste0(names(l)[i], '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Hope this helps